# React native - redux in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, redux, native

React navigation does not support redux anymore, I would like to know if it's possible to use redux to manipulate the state of my app and not the navigation state.

It may be a silly question, but I am new to redux and can't figure that out or find info about it.

Comment: No problem, I use the two of the side by side with no issues, at least so far

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Redux does not pose any constraints on React Navigation.  They are separate libraries with separate functions in your app.  The state handling in your components will be delegated to Redux, but doesn't care about what type of navigation you're using.

A good tutorial on Redux:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers